# Rsync keep full symlink directory structure

Tags: rsync, symlink

So, I am trying to keep the synlink structure when transfering files, so my folder structure:

```
$HOME/backup/backup/symlinks
    - $HOME/Documents/hello.txt
$HOME/backup/backup/data
```

Now, when I sync I want to keep the symlinks full folder structure.

**What it does now:**

```
$HOME/backup/backup/symlinks
    - $HOME/Documents/hello.txt
$HOME/backup/backup/data
    - hello.txt
```

**What I want it to do**

```
$HOME/backup/backup/symlinks
    - $HOME/Documents/hello.txt
$HOME/backup/backup/data
    - /home/user/Documents/hello.txt (aka, create the full structure inside the backup/data folder)
```

So, I want create a full path inside my data folder, to where the original symlinks content came from.

I have tried the following:

```
rsync -a ${BACKUP}/backup/symlinks/ /${BACKUP}/backup/data/
rsync -aK ${BACKUP}/backup/symlinks/ /${BACKUP}/backup/data/
rsync -aKL ${BACKUP}/backup/symlinks/ /${BACKUP}/backup/data/
```

Is this possible with rsync? If so, how can I got about achieving this.

Comment: So this is not a question about copying `hello.txt` as a symbolic link or as the file that the link points to, but to replace that directory entry (the symbolic link file) with the full pathname of the file linked to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to resolve the links first and then run rsync on the individual files. That way it can keep the resolved directory structure via `-R`. Ie. try this on Linux:

```bsh
rsync -avRL --files-from=<(find ${BACKUP}/backup/symlinks/ -exec readlink -f {} \;) / /${BACKUP}/backup/data/
```

and this on Mac OS:

```bsh
rsync -avRL --files-from=<(find ${BACKUP}/backup/symlinks/ -exec readlink {} \;) / /${BACKUP}/backup/data/
```

It assumes that the `find` command outputs the correct absolute paths, ie. that `${BACKUP}` is an absolute directory.